# Check disk before installing ubuntu, gave me error in 1 file

Tags: system-installation

I used UNetbootin to make a bootable USB to install Ubuntu 10.4 TLS, during installation, at 55%, I got an error [errn5] or something like that, next time I rebooted, I checked the disk to see if there's errors, at the end it said " error in 1 file ", what now ? How do I fix it? How do I know which file?

Answer (score 2):

I would check the md5sum of your downloaded iso.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

If it fails that - you will have to redownload it, preferably with a torrent - that will make sure your download is good.

---

Important point from Eliah Kagan in comment

> In addition to checking the MD5SUM of the downloaded .iso file, if that doesn't reveal a corrupted file, then it's important to check the installation media itself (this applies to both CD/DVD media and to USB flash drives)

Comment: In addition to checking the MD5SUM of the downloaded `.iso` file, if that doesn't reveal a corrupted file, then it's important to [check the installation media itself](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html) (this applies to both CD/DVD media and to USB flash drives).